# high charts - mapbubble

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps

Im trying to simply render highcharts bubble map in my series data. I have a custom geo json for the map data, and the 'data' property in the 2nd object of series: has a structure of {z: some_number, location_id: location_number}

If I comment out the 2nd object, it renders an empty map which is the 1st object in series quoted below.(as intended).
If I comment out the 1st object, it renders nothing which is the 2nd object in series quoted below.(my problem)

Here is one of the examples I was working with: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/map-bubble/

So my question is what am I missing? I have highmaps in there, or I would assume I wouldn't even be able to load a map?

    `//on the Highcharts extended class file:
    import Highcharts from 'highcharts'
    import Exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting'
    import Map from 'highcharts/modules/map'
    Exporting(Highcharts)
    Map(Highcharts)//imports highmaps from Map module
    //this is in bubblemap file:
    [
      {//first series object
        name: 'base map',
        mapData: mapData,
        color: '#E0E0E0',
        enableMouseTracking: false
      },
      {//second series object
        type: 'mapbubble',
        mapData: mapData,
        name: datapoint.name,
        joinBy: 'location_id',
        data: data,
        minSize: 4,
        maxSize: '12%',
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{point.z}'
        },
        color: '#000000'
      }
    ]`

Any help would be amazing. thanks.

Comment: I am not sure what should you required chart look like or where is the problem since demo you posted is working fine. Could you recreate your problem in a JSFiddle with hard-coded, exemplary data?

Comment: that actually worked? :) A co worker solved the issue. Was kind of tricky since it was silent failing... You need to import in the highcharts-more.js into highcharts as a module. so basically: 
```import WhateverHighchartsMore from 'highcharts-more'```
```WhateverHighchartsMore(Highcharts)```
*** i recommended better naming than 'whatever' :)

Comment: Since it's the solution you should post it as an answer and mark it accepted :)